# How to find out the keywords in two hadoop tables with Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have two tables in HDFS. One table (Table-1) has some keywords as you can see below. Another table (Table-2) has a text column. Every row could have more than one keyword in Table-1. I need to find out all the matched keywords in Table-1 for the text column in Table-2, and output the keyword list for every row in Table-2.

Example :

Table-1:

```
ID  | Name    | Age | City | Gender
---------------------------------
111 | Micheal | 19  | NY   | male   
222 | George  | 23  | CA   | male
333 | Linda   | 22  | LA   | female
```

Table-2:

```
Text_Description
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-Linda and my cousin left the house.  
2-Michael who is 19 year old, and George are going to rock concert in CA.
3-Shopping card is ready at the NY for male persons.
```

Output:

```
1- Linda
2- Micheal, 19, George, CA
3- NY, male
```

Comment: please share the codes you have tried so far pointing out the faulty code?

Comment: if table1 is small, you might be able to change it to a list of strings, broadcast it, and then map over table2. Not sure how to handle it when t1 is too large for that.